# Ошибка при нажатии кнопки "изменить"

Tags: delphi

Есть три кнопки "добавить" "изменить" "удалить"ю Если я нажимаю "Изменить" то появляется вторая форма в которой есть поля ввода инфы и две кнопки "ок" и "отмена" если в полях я что либо изменяю то кнопка ок срабатывает без проблем а если я например передумал что либо менять то при нажатии "ок" вылезает ошибка "ADOQuery1: Dataset not in edit or insert mode."
Код кнопки "ок":

```
procedure TForm6.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin Form5.ADOQuery1.post;
close;
end
```

плиз. хелп! Как избавиться от ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас форма для ввода данных модальная, то тут можно и по-другому поступить: не в обработчиках нажатия кнопки "ок" или "отмена", а делать это после её вызова, т. е., когда она уже закрылась. Например:

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  mr: Integer; // результат закрытия модальной формы
begin
  qry1.Edit; // открываю запрос для редактирования
  mr:=Form2.ShowModal; // показываю форму модально
  If (mr=mrOk) Then // если изменение подтвердилось
    qry1.Post // сохраняю
  Else
    qry1.Cancel; //отменяю
end;
```

Самое главное: не забудьте у кнопок указать свойство ModalResult (у кнопки "ок" mrOk, а у кнопки "отмена" mrCancel (или другое, т. к. в приведённом примере сохранение произойдёт только при нажатии на кнопку "ок", даже, если форрму закрывать на крестик)), если Вы используете кнопки BitBtn, то можете указать свойство Kind (bkOk и bkCancel соответственно) и свойство ModalResult  у них выставится автоматически.

Comment: Коллега прочитайте код его ошибки.
У него датасет не работает на изменение, но вообще логично все операции делать SQL запросами только меняя сам запрос в зависимости от нужд.

Comment: Я просто предложил свой вариант, как я бы сам сделал. Конечно же, можно делать всё только одними запросами.

Comment: @savro, датасет сам переходит в режим редактирования если происходит изменение в компонентах, связанных с его datasource'ом. Если изменений не было, то и режима редактирования не возникает, соответственно и post не проходит. то, что запрос редактируемый, вытекает из того, что при изменениях кнопка ok срабатывает как надо. код в ответе верный. надо принудительно переводить в режим редактирования, затем по закрытию постить или отменять изменения.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov  я об этом написал 5 часов назад.
Но сильно сжато :)

Comment: @savro Краткость - СТ. Понимаю :)

Answer (score 0):

для изменить нужно **EDIT** ,а не **POST**